# Laptop cooling slacking off

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling

Recently i've ran into the problem that my laptop had collected too much dust inside and starts overheating in difficult tasks (i.e. games), this happens every half a year or so,  as always i opened it, cleaned the fan with the air duster, and put everything back together.

So i thought i'd test everything and the problem became even worse, it is now overheating even while watching movies. the fan is definitely still working i can hear it spinning inside, and i can feel the  **COOL** air coming out of the side of the laptop, where the fan is located, while the middle of the laptop where the cpu and gpu are located becomes really hot.

Is there anything i can do to fix this? would buying a new fan help?

Model is: Acer aspire 5742G

Thanks in advance for any kind of help

EDIT: I've found out what the problem was, turns out there was a little piece stuck inside the fan which prevented it from rotating at full speed, which i only discovered after taking the laptop apart again.

Comment: What does it do exactly when it "overheats"

Comment: well, when goes past 100C on the cpu it just shuts down

Comment: Your computer reaching 100C is more then just dust that indicates hardware failure.  The fact you have replaced the thermal paste before indicates thats likely the cause ( thats a horrible idea with laptops ).

Comment: why would that be a bad idea? it worked fine for almost half a year, the problem with going past 100C started only after i've cleaned the dust yesterday.

Comment: There are several.  The most important.  Laptops are design with very specific thermal designs.  Even the thermal paste density is considered.

Answer (score 0):

Your thermal paste may have become old and hard... try taking off the heat sink, removing the remnants of thermal paste and applying new thermal paste.

Comment: i have changed it about 5 months ago or so, is it really that quick?